# Next-Auth signIn: Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected

Tags: typescript, eslint, next-auth, typescript-eslint, trpc.io

`<button onClick={() => signIn()}>Login</button>` is giving the following `@typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises` error in VS Code: `Promise-returning function provided to attribute where a void return was expected.`

I am following this tutorial: https://youtu.be/nzJsYJPCc80?t=642 (which doesn't seem to be getting the error)

I created this project with `npm create t3-app@latest <project-name>` and added all: trpc, tailwind, next-auth, & prisma (ie everything that create-t3-app provides).

Should I just disable this eslint error with `/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-misused-promises */` as suggested in the "Quick Fix"? Or update the default .eslintrc.json provided by create-t3-app?

Any direction would be greatly appreciated

```
// src/pages/index.tsx

import { type NextPage } from "next";
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import { signIn, signOut, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

import { api } from "../utils/api";

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Create T3 App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create-t3-app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Login</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can add void as the return type of the function, like so:

```
 <button onClick={() => void signIn()}>Login</button>
```